# count items jquery template

Tags: jquery, templates, count, compare

How do i count the items in a each jquery template and the apply a if to that variable

something like

```
<script id="inventorySummaryTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
<tr>
{{each response}}
    {{if response.length === 2 }}
        </tr><tr>
    {{/if}}
        <td><img src='${icon}'> ${title} </td>
{{/each}}

</tr>
```

This is the javascript that loads the JSON and interacts with the jquery.TMPL

```
 var ip = window.location.hash;


    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ajax/dashboard/widgets/inventorySummary.xsp?ip='+ip.substring(1),
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    request.done(function(data){
        $("#inventorySummaryTmpl").tmpl(data).appendTo("#inventorySummaryContent");
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log(textStatus)
    });
```

And the JSON

```
{

"response": [
    {
        "icon": "workstation",
        "nbItems": "38",
        "title": "Workstations"
    },
    {
        "icon": "server",
        "nbItems": "2",
        "title": "Servers"
    }
]
```

}

if someone has any ideeas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close. The variable in the `each` statement needs to be the full collection you are looping through. You can also pass custom variable names for the index and value of each item in the collection. Based on your code, the following should work, but if you posted the structure of your collection, we'd be able to ensure that it does

```
<script id="inventorySummaryTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
<tr>
    {{each(index,resp) responses}}
        {{if resp.length === 2 }}
            </tr><tr>
        {{/if}}
        <td><img src='${resp.icon}'> ${resp.title} </td>
    {{/each}}
</tr>
```

jQuery Docs: http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/

**UPDATE**

I've updated my solution now that I see what you're after. If you want to start a new `ul` (or `tr`) after every three (or six, or whatever) elements in the `response` array, check the index of the current element, not the length of the full response array.

```
<script id="inventorySummaryTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
  <ul>
    {{each(i,el) response}}
      {{if (i > 0 && i % 3 === 0) }}
        </ul><ul>
      {{/if}}
      <li class="inventoryWrap">
        <img src='blueprint/images/wrap/icons/${icon}.png' class="inventoryPic"> 
        <span class="inventoryCount">${el.nbItems}</span> 
        <span class="inventoryText">${el.title}</span>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/ZzddF/1/

Comment: I will test it out and let everyone know. in about 2-3 hours

Comment: ok So I updated the main post and I am letting you know that it dosen't work... you have the full info so you can test it.

Comment: maybe you could help by explaining what you want the final HTML output to look like. I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you want your template to do.

Comment: I want after the 6th element to add a BR (so to speak)

Comment: Here is a what it comes out of it now http://jsfiddle.net/ZzddF/   lets say that i need after the 3rd to add a break